# public class Y public static void main(String args[])

Tags: java, main

Hola soy nuevo en java y me encuentro con que aparece siempre o al menos casi siempre esto al inicio

```
public class algo {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
    }
}
```

Me preguntaba que significa exactamente

Comment: Sinceramente, si todavía no conoces que es una clase, si todavía no sabes que es un método y ni conoces los modificadores que existen en java, no deberías preocuparte aún por saber que significan esas cosas. Solo ten en cuenta que tu programa empezará a ejecutarse por el método main y a partir de ahi comienza a explorar el lenguaje. Entiende que es un objeto, cómo crearlo,, que es una clase, qué es una interfaz, que significa static, y cuando conozcas el lenguaje bien, créeme, todo hace "click". Ahora mismo, si no entiendes esos conceptos, no creo ninguna explicación te vaya a satisfacer.

Comment: El método principal o `main` hace que una clase de Java sea una aplicación es decir cuando se ejecute de forma automática la máquina virtual de java invoque este método `main` o principal y se ejecute todas las tareas, todos los procesos, los objetos, instancias, de nuestra aplicación que tengamos dentro de este método, es el boostrap o arranque, puerta de entrada de nuestra aplicación.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Java es un lenguaje de programación orientada a objetos por lo que el código lo modulamos en clases. Dentro de las clase habrá atributos, métodos,... La función `public static void main(String args[ ])` es aquella en la que normalmente ejecutaremos el código.

Muchos IDE al crear un proyecto te crean ya una clase predeterminada con el método `main`.
En resumen, por ahora, es el método en el que ejecutaremos el código.

`main` en castellano significa principal